# Map variable amount of urls to HandleFunc

Tags: go

This is the first time that I attempt to write a small blog using Go (Golang). Right now, I have a small website running with only a few pages. My `main` contains this.

```
http.HandleFunc("/about", about)
http.HandleFunc("/contact", contact)
http.HandleFunc("/", homepage)
if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

My first question is: What is this called? I call it mapping URLs to functions, but my Google results haven't been fruitful with those search terms. Is this called "routing"?

Secondly, my goal is to write a small blog app. I want to use a database to save blog posts and other data. However, mapping URLs to functions like I did above doesn't seem right because there is no way to know what the URL should be until someone makes a blog post. I would want the URL to match the blog post title. In addition, there could be hundreds of blog posts, so writing a bunch of `http.HandleFunc`s seems unreasonable.

Finally, my question is this: What options are available to solve this obstacle?

Comment: You may find this article helpful: https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/ . It's a guided tour to creating a wiki from scratch. It could easily be adapted for a blog. Final code listing at https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/final.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other approach for a "blog app" is a **static site generator**.
You can find a good example in [gohugo](http://gohugo.io/) ([repo GitHub](https://github.com/spf13/hugo)), which means [you only have one Handler](https://github.com/spf13/hugo/blob/4a2f16f91e213b02f008405938fe289c58820e88/commands/hugo.go#L395-L402):

```
if port > 0 {
    if !viper.GetBool("DisableLiveReload") {
        livereload.Initialize()
        http.HandleFunc("/livereload.js", livereload.ServeJS)
        http.HandleFunc("/livereload", livereload.Handler)
    }
    go serve(port)
}
```

But more generally, what it is called is a **router**, and you can see them in this excellent **[Guide to 3rd Party Routers in Go 2014/11/20](http://nicolasmerouze.com/guide-routers-golang/)**:

- [Gorilla mux web toolkit](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux)
- [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter)
- [Pat](https://github.com/bmizerany/pat)